# Access denied to get secret in Hashicorp Vault but able to see the secret on the web

Tags: hashicorp-vault

I'm new with Vault and I'm receiving Access denied for everything using the CLI. For example, I can see the engines and a secret at https://vault.corp.companyABC.com/ui/vault/secrets/the-app/show/something/my-secret but when I execute `vault kv get the-app/something/my-secret` I get access denied. Or if I run `vault read sys/mounts` or `vault secrets list` I get access denied. When I login I execute `vault login --method=okta username=name.lastname` I get a token (that starts with hvs.S0meLetTerS) and a token accessor, I tried setting the environment variables as VAULT_ADDR=https://vault.corp.companyABC.com and VAULT_TOKEN=theTokenFromLogin and it's the same. What am I doing wrong?

Attached authorization:

```
token_policies         ["devops-myapp-all-admin-policy-admin" "devops-myapp-cicd-policy-admin" "devops-myapp-mgmt-policy-admin" "devops-myapp-prd-policy-admin" "devops-myapp-stg-policy-admin" "devops-myapp-test-policy-admin" "default"]
identity_policies      []
policies               ["devops-myapp-all-admin-policy-admin" "devops-myapp-cicd-policy-admin" "devops-myapp-mgmt-policy-admin" "devops-myapp-prd-policy-admin" "devops-myapp-stg-policy-admin" "devops-myapp-test-policy-admin" "default"]
token_meta_policies    devops-myapp-all-admin-policy-admin,devops-myapp-cicd-policy-admin,devops-myapp-mgmt-policy-admin,devops-myapp-prd-policy-admin,devops-myapp-stg-policy-admin,devops-myapp-test-policy-admin
token_meta_username    name.lastname
```

Comment: What is the attached authorization policy?